# Including admin-options.php file in Child Themes

Tags: functions, child-theme, include

My theme uses the following in functions.php

> require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/admin-options.php';

I want to override this with my own version of the admin-options.php file, which I have stored in my Child Theme directory.

As per Codex instructions on [Referencing / Including Files in Your Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Referencing_.2F_Including_Files_in_Your_Child_Theme) I've tried adding the following line in my Child Theme functions.php file

> require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/admin-options.php' );

both with and without commenting out the require_once line in the theme functions.php file.

Neither way works - the site won't load at all.

Echoing the line in my Child Theme functions.php gives the correct path for the admin-options.php file I want to include:

> echo ( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/admin-options.php');

returns wp-content/themes/onetone-child/admin-options.php

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in wordpress you can't override a file of functions of a parent theme, the only thing that can do is to make an override of the functions of this file in your functions.php of your child theme.

```
if ( ! function_exists ( 'my_function' ) ) {
    function my_function() {
        // Contents of your function here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh yes, quite right!! ...thanks :-)

https://www.mhthemes.com/support/overriding-parent-theme-functions-child-theme-tutorial/

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623